# Facebook doesn't pull image preview, title, etc. when sharing a link from domain

Tags: facebook, sharing

I'm having an issue that is boggling my mind for a few days now.

Sharing of the exact same content is not working on www.raptorsrepublic.com but fine on forums.raptorsrepublic.com (or any other domain).

I simply can't share (i.e., generate previews, title, etc.) links from www.raptorsrepublic.com, but when I post the exact same content from a different domain (as a test, forums.raptorsrepublic.com), it works.

Even the graph debug tool crashes on any link from www.raptorsrepublic.com, but works fine for forums.raptorsrepublic.com.  Here's an example:

http://forums.raptorsrepublic.com/y.html
http://www.raptorsrepublic.com/y.html

Exact same content, but one works (forums.raptorsrepublic.com) and one doesn't (www.raptorsrepublic.com) and the latter even crashes Facebook's share debug tool.

Can you please help me in getting this working so I can share links from the domain www.raptorsrepublic.com?

Note that the domain is not blacklisted as I can actually post the link fine.